# Search TFS Build Process Parameters

Tags: tfs, build

We have hundreds of builds on our TFS server. We have a template for the process parameters. We used to have a few different deployment strategies and people would customize the default build quality to trigger a different strategy. Now we have consolidated and removed some of the build quality options. How can I do a search to find all the builds that use the outdated (and now deleted) options for default build quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box command for what you ask. You can use [Community TFS Build Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f) to set the a parameter to a new value.

If you need a more complex logic, you must write a tool yourself.
It not that hard and you can use [this sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/03/25/tfs2010-queuing-a-build-from-code-with-custom-process-parameter-values.aspx) or [WilBar's code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/archive/2010/06/03/deserializing-process-parameters.aspx) as a starting point for C#, or at Community TFS Build Manager sources.

Comment: Is this functionality not part of the Community Build Manager?

Comment: Got to keep up Giulio